# How to get response data on Android using Apollo client for GraphQL if http code is not 200?

Tags: android, http, graphql, apollo

I'm new to GraphQL using the Apollo client on Android. I'm trying to sign up a user on the server via graphQL mutation.

I call a mutation and if user's data is not valid I get http code 422: Unprocessible Entity, and in this case I cannot get any response details. I use standard way to make a call:

```
.enqueue(object : ApolloCall.Callback<CreateUserMutation.Data>() {
                    override fun onFailure(e: ApolloException) {
                    }
                    override fun onResponse(response: 
Response<CreateUserMutation.Data>) {
                    }
```

And after this I'm in the onFailure block. ApolloException contains only http code description. But I want to see error details in a full response, that I can see via the Postman. I've already tried com.apollographql.apollo.ApolloCall.Callback#onHttpError callback, but the networkResponse body = null. I've described this problem here, but haven't fixed my problem:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/1166

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to check if `ApolloException` is an `instanceof ApolloHttpException`.

If it is, you can get the `throwable.rawResponse().code()` from it.

If it's not it means it isn't server error (maybe timeout or others)